# Yocto sumo with RPI3B+ with older Boost

Tags: boost, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I have updated a *meta-layer* for an application based on RPI3B to Yocto sumo release. The reason why I am using now *RPI3B+* (instead of *RPI3B*).
When doing so, I run into a problem that **Boost** library **1.66.0** (in sumo) is not compatible with the one i used in previous build **1.64.0**.

Is there a way to force *Yocto* in my configuration to start using boost 1.64.0 instead of the 1.66.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

*Yocto* allows to choose preferred version of recipe with using - [PREFERRED_VERSION](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_VERSION), add into config file line:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_boost = "1.64.0"
```

Proof:

```
$ bitbake -s | grep -e Preferred -e ^boost\\s
Recipe Name                                    Latest Version         Preferred Version
boost                                              :1.67.0-r0                :1.64.0-r0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,
i tried this option and got
"NOTE: preferred version 1.64.0 of boost not available (for item boost)
NOTE: versions of boost available: 1.66.0"

I assume that it is not possible to change the boost version, since many other packages are using it?

Comment: Based on this error I assume that in Your conf/bblayers.conf file is not added path to layer contain Boost in 1.64.0 version or You are working on updated poky branch (to sumo) with updated recipe. You have to manually add this recipe to some layer (or next to boost recipes); PREFERRED_VERSION helps choose between both or more recipes with different versions that's are available in workspace (off-course configured conf/bblayers.conf file). Based on this I am updating my answer with proof.